# How to Run a Python Code in the Terminal from Jupyter Lab (Mac)

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am new to Jupyter Lab. I would like to run a code in Python directly from the Terminal section in Jupyter Lab.

I have tried the following:

[image: Jupyter Try]

but I couldn't figure it out.

Can anyone help?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are simply not in the good directory where `puppy.py` is located.
Use the shell command [`cd`](http://pwet.fr/man/linux/commandes/posix/cd/) (**c**hange **d**irectory) to navigate to `Computer Vision/`

My guess is

```sh
cd Computer\ Vision/
python3 puppy.py
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Just for seak of curiosity, Computer Vision is a folder I created in Jupyter Lab. Do I find it also on my computer or just in the notebook?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Jupyter Lab. I'm using Jupyter notebooks, though. And if one creates a new directory with their front end, it actually creates the directory on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're in the correct directory. Right now you are in your home folder (your user) but the code appears to be under "Computer Vision"